# Scrolling touch event on ListView interepreted as click in javascript in list item WebView

Tags: android, webview

I have a `ListView` where each item contains a `WebView`. Each of these web views is actually displaying a video player, loaded from an external source. The content of each WebView has a fixed height and is displayed in full and I'm avoiding any scrolling-within-scrolling issues by settings:

```
_webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
_webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

My problem is that when you swipe the list view to scroll the items (which works fine), the player inside the WebView interprets this as a click and starts playing the video. I guess from the WebView's perspective, the mouse went down at point x, and came up at the same point, so it seems like a click.

Is there any way I can overlay some kind of transparent view on top or do some other trickery so that only single tap gestures make it to the WebView, and any swiping / moving gesture is treated as normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve this one by myself. The trick is to subclass the `WebView`, then override the `onTouchEvent` method like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    // If this web view gets sent a 'CANCEL' event, it means the parent list view has intercepted the event (for scrolling), so we want to catch it, otherwise it propogates into the HTML and starts the video
    int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);
    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

What I finally worked out is that the enclosing ListView is already intercepting the touch events when there's a proper swipe, which sends the `ACTION_CANCEL` event to the WebView. By catching that `ACTION_CANCEL` event in the `onTouchEvent` method, it prevents the event from going down into the HTML in the WebView.